# Package execution failed using DTEXEC /SQ

Tags: ssis

I have deployed a package through SQL Server Deployment to a Custom Folder "Folder1" under MSDB. The execution failed using DTEXEC. What is the correct syntax using DTEXEC ?

Comment: What was the exact command you used? What does "execution failed" mean? Did you get an error? If so, what was it? If not, what happened?

Answer (score 1):

[dtexec utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
dtexec /sql \Folder1\MyPackage /server MyServer
```

Note that for packages deployed to SQL Server, the file extension is not present while execution of a package on the file system would require the .dtsx extension.